# Bring a UIView to the front for `UICollectionViewController`

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

We have a photo browser which we can use to select multiple images and do something with them. However, the process is slow. Therefore, we want to show a progress view on top of the `UICollection` View when the user hit import button.

However, it seems that I cannot arrange the order of the view in interface builder (in storyboard). I also tried the following `bringSubviewToFront` function in code and it is not working either.

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.progressView];
```

Any idea how to do this?

BTW, in the following screenshot, the highlighted `View` is linked to:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *progressView;
```

[image]

Edit:

I am pretty sure that we could create a subview on top of a `UITableView`. But it seems that it is impossible to do so for `UICollectionView`?

2nd Edit:

Another screenshot, the arrange buttons are disabled.

[image]

3rd edit:

Eventually, I decided to do all these in code and everything works fine (>_<). If anybody know how to solve the issue with the interface builder, I will still very much appreciate it.

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[self.view addSubview:view];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:view];
```

Comment: self.collectionView instead of self.view? bringSubviewToFront only works for direct child views.

Comment: are you truing to add a progress indicator to each cell\

Comment: @MithunMadhav, nope. I am trying to add one for the whole view.

Comment: hmm.. 'View'(in the screenshot) is the view you are truing to display ??

Comment: @MithunMadhav, Yes. I cannot move it around though.

Comment: @cdstamper just tried. Not working either.

Comment: You're trying to position this view outside the collectionView?

Comment: @YuchenZhong : You mean you can't move the view out of the collection view's hierarchy in Storyboard

Comment: Because i'm sure if you move the collection view around in Interfacebuilder, you will find that 'View' is underneath it

Comment: @MithunMadhav Sorry, I meant I cannot move it up and down which is how we order them in the interface builder.

Comment: if your progressView will always be on top you could always [progressView.layer setZPosition:MAXFLOAT]; if it's in the correct hierarchy it should come to the front (only put this in as a last ditch really).

Comment: @MithunMadhav Yes, you are right. I get your point. But the `View` is a subview of the `Collection View` and it is always behind the cells (just like background). But what I want is the view to be on top of all the cells in the collection view.

Comment: I may be wrong , but if you use the view just to show progress, can't you put it outside the collection view and disable user interaction on it ?

Comment: @Tomskiis, Yes! This works! Finally something working. But why only this works?

Comment: @MithunMadhav I wouldn't able to move the view outside of the collection view either. I guess one `View Controller` only allows at most one view inside? I am not sure. I will give it a try it with a UITableViewController now.

Comment: @MithunMadhav It's pretty dodgy but it's Friday at 5pm ;), you're basically telling the View you want it to be the Max Z Value you can get, IB Can be a bit funky sometimes (I usually stick with just code). Maybe something on your cells is always being placed above the progress view.

Comment: @MithunMadhav Yay. One UIView per UIViewController. But the UIView may have multiple subviews so it would matter that much.

Comment: View ->CollectionView, View (or am i totally not getting  the point here :D)

Comment: @MithunMadhav UIViewController -> UIView -> UICollectionView + As many Views as you want (within reason)

Comment: @MithunMadhav, @Tomskiis Okay, in my current hierarchy, it is like `UICollectionViewController`->`UICollectionView`. `UICollectionViewController` is derived class from `UIViewController`.

Comment: @MithunMadhav, but I think Tomskiis's hierarchy works as well. And maybe it is a better way to work around this problem at this point.

Comment: ok .. as long as the problem's solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to move the "View" aka "Progress View" outside of the collection view and below the photo browser in that hierarchy, which would cause it to be the front-most element in the view. The lower something is, the more forward it is.

You can then also use autolayout ("Editor" -> "Align/Pin/Arrange/etc") to reposition or center your progress view.

Comment: Alternately, add the view programmatically, or embed the collection view inside a regular view within Interface Builder.

Comment: @cdstamper Maybe embed the collection view inside a regular view is a better idea to go.

Comment: @Ross Barbish, I tried. All these buttons are in grey. I am not able to attach screenshots here. Please refer to my second edit in the post.

Comment: @YuchenZhong - Yea, I would first create a container uiview for all your elements (photo browser, collection view, progressview) that fills the entire bounds of the screen. Then move the progress view to where I mentioned within that new superview. Then ensure that the progress view is selected. Then you should definitely see options enabled, like "Editor" -> "Pin" -> "Top space to superview" and others.